# Drop down menu width issue

Tags: css, menu

Despite of many efforts, I am unable to make the drop down menu of the same width as of the parent. Please help me out. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/XLxJk/)

```
#menu, #menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#menu {
    width: 958px;
    /*margin: 60px auto;*/
    border: 1px solid #222;
    background-color: #111;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#444, #111);

    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777;
}
#menu:before,
#menu:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

#menu:after {
    clear: both;
}

#menu {
    zoom:1;
}
#menu li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #222;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    position: relative;
}

#menu a {
    float: left;
    padding: 11px 40px;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

#menu li:hover > a {
    color: #fafafa;
}

*html #menu li a:hover { /* IE6 only */
    color: #fafafa;
}
#menu ul {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000000;    
    background: #444;    
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);    

    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;  
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 150px;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;


    _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);        
}

#menu ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    _line-height: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111, 0 2px 0 #666;
}

#menu ul li:last-child {   
    box-shadow: none;    
}

#menu ul a {    
    padding: 10px;
    width: 130px;
    _height: 10px; /*IE6 only*/
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
}

#menu ul a:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
}
#menu ul li:first-child > a {
    /*border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;*/
    padding: 11px 13px;
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: -6px;
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:after {
    left: -6px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    border-left: 0;    



}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-bottom-color: #000; 
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-right-color: #000; 
    border-bottom-color: transparent;     
}

#menu ul li:last-child > a {
    /*border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px*/;
    padding: 11px 20px;

}
​

HTML:

<ul id="menu">

                                                          <li><a href="#">About </a></li>

                                                          <li><a href="#">Programmes</a>
                                                          <ul>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Undergraduate</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Postgraduate</a></li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                          </li>
                                                          <li><a href="#">Academics</a></li>
                                                          <li><a href="#">Research</a></li>
                                                          <li><a href="#">Facilities</a></li>
                                                          <li></li>             
                                        </ul>  

    ​
```

Comment: You coud use Twitter Bootstrap ->http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

Comment: It helps, when posting sample code to remove all the extra non-essential styling markup - there's a lot to weed through in this JS fiddle. (This will also help in debugging the code on your own)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the dropdown menu ul element add "right: 0" (or -1px in your case to take into account the borders):

```
#menu ul {
margin: 20px 0 0 0;
_margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 38px;
left: 0;
right: -1px /*  <-- add this */
z-index: 1000000;    
background: #444;    
background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);    

transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Then remove the width property in the a element:

```
#menu ul a {    
padding: 10px;
_height: 10px; /*IE6 only*/
display: block;
white-space: nowrap;
float: none;
text-transform: none;
}
```

This will work independently of the menu container width.

working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/chopsticks/XLxJk/4/

Comment: Thanks. That worked very fine. I am still having a small issue that when I move to the drop down menu from the parent, the drop down menu gets invisible. Please have a look

Comment: It works fine in the fiddle, but not in the real code :(

Comment: Try mine then. width: 100% should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
#menu ul a {    
 padding: 10px;
 width: 150px;
 _height: 10px; /*IE6 only*/
 display: block;
 white-space: nowrap;
 float: none;
 text-transform: none;
}
#menu ul li:first-child > a {
 padding: 11px 20px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/XLxJk/2/)

Answer (score 1):

So by positioning your dropdown menu absolutely you are removing it from the flow. This causes it to no longer size to the width of it's parent element. You'll need to explicitly set the width, set the width explicitly via js (if you want the menu items to size based on the text they contain) or figure out how to position it differently so it inherits the width.

Answer (score 1):

How about this ?

Just set the width to 100% in the #menu ul, and you have a dropdown of the same size.

http://jsfiddle.net/XLxJk/3/

Comment: Thanks. Your code is also good :)